# Creating an ElasticSearch index mixing two CouchDB rivers

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

I am trying to index two different CouchDB databases with Elastic Search, using a single index, but it seems that only one of the two databases is actually indexed. The documents from the other database are simply not included in the index.

Is there any limitation about the number of rivers which can be connected to a given index?

I am unable to find any documentation about this specific use case ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create two index with one river for each.
Afaik you can not have multiple rivers for the same index. See the content of your _river index.

BTW you should ask questions to the elasticsearch.org mailing list.

Comment: Thanks. Question is now on the mailing list too.